# How to average values in list of lists that contain same parameter

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I want to average the 2nd values in all lists that contain the same 1st value, and convert these averaged lists into a new list of lists.

For example i want to convert this:

```
[['foo', 13], 
['foo', 15], 
['bar', 14], 
['bar', 16],
['bar', 5]]
```

to this:

```
[['foo', avg(13+15)], 
['bar', avg(14+16+5)]]
```

Any ideas of a simple way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why not use dictionary ?

Comment: ah, thanks CDJB, i didn't find that, yes that answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby
from statistics import mean # 3 or greater

# if using 2.7
def mean(x): return sum(x)/len(x)

a = [['foo', 13], 
['foo', 15], 
['bar', 14], 
['bar', 16],
['bar', 5]]

[[key, mean(map(lambda x: x[1], list(group)))] for key, group in groupby(a, lambda x:x[0])]

# [['foo', 14], ['bar', 11]]
```

Groups the list on the first element then computes the mean. Assumes you have a mean function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You could have easily used dictionary for this problem. Though there might be better approaches, this is one of the approach.

```
l=[['foo', 13], ['foo', 15], ['bar', 14], ['bar', 16], ['bar', 5]]
dictionary={}
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    if l[i][0] in dict:
        dictionary[l[i][0]].append(l[i][1])
    else:
        dictionary[l[i][0]]=[l[i][1]]
# The above dictionary basically stores all the elements belonging to a key in a list which we can get by referring the key.
l=[]
for keys in dict:
    l.append([keys,sum(dictionary[keys])/len(dictionary[keys])]) #If you want 2d list as the output
    dictionary[keys]=sum(dictionary[keys])/len(dictionary[keys])

print(dictionary) # Prints {'foo': 14.0, 'bar': 11.666..}
print(l) # Prints [['foo', 14.0], ['bar', 11.666666666666666]] and order isn't maintained.
```

Comment: `dict` is a reserved built-in keyword.

Comment: Yes but we can use that right ? or not ? Are there any problems in using it ? OMG All these years I have used dict despite knowing it's a keyword cause it is readable, didn't knew its a bad practice. I changed the dict to dictionary btw.

Comment: By assigning a value to `dict` you are changing the actual `dict` and you won't be able to use it anymore. 
`>>> type(dict) 
<class 'type'> 
>>> dict = {'a': 1} 
>>> type(dict) 
<class 'dict'> 
>>> isinstance({'a':1}, dict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types`